# Outlook vs Outlook.com

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Since Hotmail has become Outlook.com there have been a lot of questions on this SE about the transition and about changes to functionality. Many questions just refer to "Outlook" or use the "Outlook" tag when they're actually asking about "Outlook.com" (arguably a different beast entirely).

Any questions here will almost certainly be about Outlook.com, as any Outlook-related questions would probably end up on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). So, should we go through and change references from Outlook to Outlook.com where applicable? Setting these as synonyms would probably suffice for tagging, but what about question titles and bodies - are they worth editing en masse?

Comment: I found one or two and you probably the rest. Thanks for making us aware !!

Comment: I think consensus has been made. Perhaps you can mark the answer or answer your own.

Comment: Done! I hadn't realised you could accept answers Meta too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The larger part of the existing outlook tags (approx. 60) should remain as they are. Many of them relate to the native Outlook, often in combination with the web based Outlook or Gmail.

The new questions, about Outlook.com, should be re-tagged accordingly and reviewed. If many haven't been changed, we didn't pay attention during the review process.