# Are five [outlook...] tags sufficient?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I don’t use Outlook and am confused by our tags for that which, in addition to [outlook.com-calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com-calendar) (no Usage guide) include:

**[outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com)** applied to <s>253</s> 265 Open Qs, 18 Followers and a Usage guide of:

> Outlook.com is a webmail service from Microsoft.

(This has tag [hotmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotmail) and tag [windows-live-mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live-mail) as synonyms and tag [outlook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook) has been suggested as another. At least 19 users have the score necessary to vote on the suggestion, but none have.)

**[outlook-web-access](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook-web-access)** applied to <s>32</s> 47 Open Qs, 2 Followers and a Usage guide of:

> The Web based e-mail client from Microsoft

Its wiki includes:

> Outlook Web App Microsoft's web based client, capable of accessing e-mail,calendars, contacts, tasks, documents.

**[outlook-365](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook-365)** applied to <s>10</s> 11 Open Qs, 1 Follower and no Usage guide nor wiki.

**[outlook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook)** applied to <s>60</s> 59 Open Qs, 6 Followers and a Usage guide of:

> For questions regarding Microsoft's webmail service, please use outlook.com as the tag. Questions on the desktop client are off-topic and will be closed.

(A suggestion that this be made a synonym of [outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com) has been pending since April.)

Say for someone who *does* use "Outlook" is it clear enough which of the above tags to use in which circumstances, or might additional guidance be helpful?

Related:
[Outlook vs Outlook.com](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/outlook-vs-outlook-com)
[How can this Q about Outlook mail forwarding be off topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2385/how-can-this-q-about-outlook-mail-forwarding-be-off-topic)
[Synonym Request & Rename](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/synonym-request-rename)
[Clean up project: Office 365](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3952/clean-up-project-office-365)

Comment: I had taken a cursory glance at one point and it seems that some of the questions tagged `outlook` are about using the desktop application with particular online services. These questions should be evaluated as to whether they are indeed on-topic instead of being retagged `outlook.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different products.

Outlook.com is Microsoft's Gmail competitor, and used to be Window's Live Mail. It also subsumed Hotmail (thus the synonym).

Outlook 365 is part of the Office 365 suite of products. It combines desktop and web components. Consider its analog to be G Suite.

Outlook Web Access is the classical web interface for an Exchange server. It's different than Outlook 365 in that it pre-dates it by quite a lot and is not really integrated into the rest of the suite. It's meant to be a substitute for Outlook for versions before Office 365.

Outlook is the desktop mail client. It, by itself, is off-topic here, and attracts questions not only about the desktop client, but also questions that should be tagged with one of the other tags above. It'd be great if it was a synonym.

Outlook.com Calendar is the calendar companion to Outlook.com. It's a consumer Google Calendar equivalent.